# How do I enable logging with Postgres.app on OS X?

Tags: postgresql, logging, osx-mountain-lion, psql

Running **Mountain Lion**. Installed PostgreSQL via **[Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/documentation)**. Using postgres for Django via PyCharm. I've read multiple SO and [blog posts](http://architects.dzone.com/articles/configuring-logging) about getting this to work, and logs simply are not being created.

My conf file **(data directory) is located here:**

```
$ ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var/postgresql.conf
```

My **postgresql.conf logging settings** look like this:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'  
logging_collector = on  
log_directory = '~/Library/Logs/Postgres' (I've also tried 'pg_log')
```

I've **tried closing and opening Postgres.app**

I've also **tried restarting the command line server**:

```
$ /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_ctl restart -D ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var/
```

...but this results in the terminal hanging on `"LOG:  autovacuum launcher started"` ... and the **logs printing to the console**.

[This SO post is closely relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805720/display-postgres-server-logs-output-in-terminal-and-record-to-logs-at-same-time?rq=1), but I want Postgres.app to write to log files, not print to console.

Any help would be awesome, thanks.

EDIT: In response to vyegorov,

```
version = PostgreSQL 9.2.2
```

silent_mode does not exist in postgresql.conf

Comment: Which PostgreSQL version? What's the setting for `silent_mode`?

Comment: Came here wondering how to run pg_ctl with Postgres.app, was not disappointed.  Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got it working for me. Here's the settings I'm using:

```
log_destination = 'stderr'  
logging_collector = on
log_directory = '/tmp/'
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d.log'
```

Comment: great, this should be enabled by default in the app

Comment: This will not log every command. If you want every command logged, add one more line which is `log_min_duration_statement = 0`

Answer (score 3):

On the latest version it is on

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Containers/com.heroku.postgres/Data/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var/postgresql.conf

psql -U existingdatabase_name_here

then SHOW config_file;
```