# Stop PostgreSQL Printing Errors to STDOUT

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, homebrew, psycopg2

I'm getting error messages on stdout when I run queries that have errors. I think these are being printed out by PostgrSQL, but I'm not sure. Below are the steps I can use to reproduce this issue:

```
(vpgrstest) Euphorbus:~/tmp$ pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
server starting
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2017-07-19 17:56:28 UTC
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
Euphorbus:~/tmp$ pyenv virtualenv 3.6.2 vpgrstest
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/rgant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/vpgrstest/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /Users/rgant/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/envs/vpgrstest/lib/python3.6/site-packages
(vpgrstest) Euphorbus:~/tmp$ pip install psycopg2
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached psycopg2-2.7.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
Installing collected packages: psycopg2
Successfully installed psycopg2-2.7.1
(vpgrstest) Euphorbus:~/tmp$ python test.py
ERROR:  null value in column "num" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (NULL)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)", (None, ))
psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column "num" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).

(vpgrstest) Euphorbus:~/tmp$ python test.py 2>/dev/null
ERROR:  null value in column "num" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null).
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (NULL)
```

The contents of `test.py` are:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("postgresql://rgant@localhost/rgant")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, num integer NOT NULL);")
cur.execute("INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (%s)", (None, ))
```

I don't expect to see the first three lines starting "ERROR:  ", "DETAIL:  ", or "STATEMENT:  " which are printed to stdout.

Any idea what is causing that? I installed postgresql using homebrew.

```
(vpgrstest) Euphorbus:~/tmp$ brew info postgresql
postgresql: stable 9.6.3 (bottled), HEAD
Object-relational database system
https://www.postgresql.org/
Conflicts with:
  postgres-xc (because postgresql and postgres-xc install the same binaries.)
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3 (3,259 files, 36.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2017-07-05 at 14:51:21
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/postgresql.rb
==> Dependencies
Required: openssl ✔, readline ✔
==> Requirements
Optional: python ✘, python3 ✔
==> Options
--with-dtrace
    Build with DTrace support
--with-python
    Enable PL/Python2
--with-python3
    Enable PL/Python3 (incompatible with --with-python)
--without-perl
    Build without Perl support
--without-tcl
    Build without Tcl support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.0) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/upgrading.html

To migrate existing data from a previous minor version (9.0-9.5) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html

  You will need your previous PostgreSQL installation from brew to perform `pg_upgrade`.
  Do not run `brew cleanup postgresql` until you have performed the migration.

To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

To be clear, my problem isn't that there are errors (I'm intentionally creating an error), but only that the errors are being printed out by PostgreSQL (or maybe psycopg2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this behavior is the way you are starting pgsql, since you issued the command to start postgres from the command line it is running in the background and reporting to standard out.

Change the command:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```

To:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start > /dev/null
```

And you will no longer see these error messages. Or if you do want to see them but do not want them polluting your python output.

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /some/log/path.log start
```

Or you can open 2 terminal windows and run the pg_ctl command in one and your python scripts from the other.

Comment: I didn't expect pg_ctl to change the logging from stderr. I also found this question which is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805720/display-postgres-server-logs-output-in-terminal-and-record-to-logs-at-same-time