# How to redirect PostgreSQL logs to docker container stdout?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have PostgreSQL run in Docker container. Сontainer stdout is storing for audit reasons by another department.

What I need, is to have PostgreSQL logs in container stdout. Now container stdout doesn't contain PostgreSQL logs.

Could you help me? How can I add PostgreSQL logs to container stdout?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you check this once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805720/display-postgres-server-logs-output-in-terminal-and-record-to-logs-at-same-time

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this not works for me. We want to log all db queries, so we don't want to store it in log files, it's too huge. That department would like to get stdout of docker container and forward it to some log processing tool. How can we do this?

Comment: Could you provide your dockerfile?